# JavaScript - Move through array with a next and prev button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, button

I want to step through an array with a next and previous button. Each button calls the same function as it is in. I have the following code...

```
    function displayPic(i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            $('#map_holder').empty();
            $('#map_holder').append(picArray[i] + '<br><input id="next" type="button" value="Next" onclick="displayPic(' + i + 1 + ');" />');

            if (i == picArray.length - 1) {
                $('#map_holder').empty();
                $('#map_holder').append(picArray[i] + '<br><input id="prev" type="button" value="Prev" onclick="displayPic(' + i - 1 + ');" />');
            }
            else {
                $('#map_holder').empty();
                $('#map_holder').append(picArray[i] + '<br><input id="prev" type="button" value="Prev" onclick="displayPic(' + i - 1 + ');" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="next" type="button" value="Next" onclick="displayPic(' + i + 1 + ');" />');
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML. It should look something like `onclick="displayPic(01)"` and `onclick="displayPic(12)"`. Can you guess what you'd have to change? Also, `displayPic` won't do anything at all if `i > 0`.

Comment: @charlietfl: It doesn't look like they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend adding button each time with the new image displayed, it makes it more complicated. How about using a global variable `i` and building the form early with `<img>` and `<button id='prev'>` and `<button id='next'>`?

```
<div id='map_holder'></div>//this will display the image
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>

var i = 0;
displayPic(0); //show the first photo initially

$('#prev').click(function(){
    i--;
    displayPic(i);
});

$('#next').click(function(){
    i++;
    displayPic(i);
});

function displayPic(i) {        
    $('#map_holder').empty();
    $('#map_holder').append(picArray[i]);

    if(i == 0) 
        $('#prev').hide();
    else  
        $('#prev').show();     

    if(i == picArray.length-1)
        $('#next').hide();
    else
        $('#next').show();   
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/f4j884cs/1/

Comment: You might want to explain why their code does not work, so they can learn from their mistakes.

Comment: I want to render new images and buttons each time. The first image doesn't have the previous button and the last image doesn't have a next button.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, there is an issue. The outer block checks `if (i == 0)` then the inner block checks `if (i == picArray.length - 1)`. The inner block condition will never evaluate to `true` under normal circumstances because the value of `i` is guaranteed to be `0` due to the outer `if (i == 0)` condition.

Try this to start:

```
function displayPic(i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        $('#map_holder').empty();
        $('#map_holder').append(picArray[i] + '<br><input id="next" type="button" value="Next" onclick="displayPic(' + i + 1 + ');" />');
    }
    else if (i == picArray.length - 1) {
        $('#map_holder').empty();
        $('#map_holder').append(picArray[i] + '<br><input id="prev" type="button" value="Prev" onclick="displayPic(' + i - 1 + ');" />');
    }
    else {
        $('#map_holder').empty();
        $('#map_holder').append(picArray[i] + '<br><input id="prev" type="button" value="Prev" onclick="displayPic(' + i - 1 + ');" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="next" type="button" value="Next" onclick="displayPic(' + i + 1 + ');" />');
    }
}
```

If this still doesn't work, please provide further details.

Comment: Yes I have tried that a couple of times. Provided below is the initializer when a "Display Picture" is clicked. It then generates an image and a next button and calls the displayPic function.

                            $('#map_holder').append(picArray[0] + '<br><input id="next" type="button" value="Next" onclick="displayPic(1);" />');